# Change log4j2 log level from string to int

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

within the log4j2 configuration I am trying to convert the loglevels from string to an int.

[Following the directions located in log4j2 Patterns section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html)

[image snippet of example log4j2 pattern mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqhQr.png)

Following the example above I created in log4j2.xml config:

```
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" 
destinationBindingName="${sys:env}.logging" 
factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"
providerURL="${sys:log4j.providerurl}"
userName="log"
password="log">
    <PatternLayout pattern='{"Message":"%m","LogLevel":%level{Debug=1,Info=2,Warn=3,Error=4,Fatal=5,Trace=6},"Type":"middleware","App":"${app_name}","Env":"${sys:env}","data":{"Event_Time":"%d{ISO8601}","Thread":"%t","Class":"%c"}}'/>
</JMS>
```

The edited PatternLayout I would now expect would replace the string debug,info,warn etc. with the mapped int values of 1,2,3 . .

This is not the case, I still receive string value.  If someone could suggest where I am making the mistake I would appreciate it. thank you.

edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <!-- replace > app_name_here_only < with the distinct name of your service. you will use this name to search for within kibana (ex: type:middleware app:<app_name>) -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="app_name">middleware_united</Property>
    </Properties>
    <!-- do not configure below this line -->
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}${app_name}.log" filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}${app_name}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="${sys:env}.logging" factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory" factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory" providerURL="${sys:log4j.providerurl}" userName="log" password="log">
    <PatternLayout pattern='{"Type":"middleware","Env":"${sys:env}","App":"${app_name}","LogLevel":%level{Debug=1,Info=2,Warn=3,Error=4,Fatal=5,Trace=6},"Message":"%m","data":{"Event_Time":"%d{ISO8601}","Thread":"%t","Class":"%c"}}'/>
        </JMS>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN"/>
        <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log-->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
        <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="WARN"/>
        <!-- Mule classes -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO"/>
        <!-- Reduce DM verbosity -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN"/>
        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Is there any other appender or pattern in your configuration file?

Comment: @wangyuntao Yes I have a rolling file appender with its own pattern file. I added the full configuration in question.  thank you.

Comment: @wangyuntao - I do now see that it is working as expected, the ol' id10t appeared on my side.

results:

{"Type":"middleware","Env":"dev","App":"logging-test","LogLevel":2,"Message":" . . .


I appreciate your time, thank you.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your pattern but it worked well.

Here's my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern='{"Type":"middleware","Env":"${sys:env}","App":"${app_name}","LogLevel":%level{Debug=1,Info=2,Warn=3,Error=4,Fatal=5,Trace=6},"Message":"%m","data":{"Event_Time":"%d{ISO8601}","Thread":"%t","Class":"%c"}}'/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here's the output:

```
{"Type":"middleware","Env":"${sys:env}","App":"${app_name}","LogLevel":2,"Message":"b","data":{"Event_Time":"2017-03-29T11:28:14,477","Thread":"main","Class":"test.Log4j2"}}
```